# Scale image to fit in UIButton

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton

I have a problem with the UIButtons. How can I scale a image to fit their frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to combine setbackgroundimage and set to fill

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *Btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    Btn.frame = //set frame using CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);     
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image name here"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: ^^ it's a little late ive found the solution I needed to combine setbackgroundimage and set to fill